# Unity3D Switch RenderMode of Canvas Image

Tags: image, canvas, unity-game-engine, switch-statement, render

For a unity game group project my task at the moment is to find out the following: In the game the player will sooner or later find a picture (in this case a map) lying on a desk, and when clicking on the map it will become screen sized so you can look at it properly, and when clicking again the map should go back to it's place on the table. I wanna realize this by using a UI Canvas and the function OnMouseDown.

This is my code atm:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class map : MonoBehaviour {

  private Canvas MapDummy;

  void Awake()
  {
    MapDummy = GetComponent<Canvas>();
  }

  void OnMouseDown()
  {
    if(MapDummy.renderMode == RenderMode.WorldSpace)
    {
        MapDummy.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
    }
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if(MapDummy.renderMode != RenderMode.WorldSpace
       && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        MapDummy.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no error, but nothing happens. Did I put the components in the correct way? First I created a GameObject UI Canvas, added the Component Image to it and added my picture called "MapDummy" as SourceImage to the Image. I imported MapDummy as Asset with the setting "Texture Type:Sprite". Then I created the script and put it to the canvas. Is that the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Err, this code seemingly does nothing.

1. `OnMouseDown` sets to `ScreenSpaceOverlay` (as it was in world).
2. Then `Update()` come, set it back to `WorldSpace` (as it is not that).

This all happens in the same frame. Does exactly what you told it to. :)

---

I'd do it absolutely another way (something like lookat camera / scale to fit frustum, or do something similar with the camera itself). You cannot animate this, can't really customize paddings / etc.